# Obtener la dirección fisica MAC del Bluetooth y WIFI en Android M

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-m

Para obtener la dirección física `MAC` del bluetooth,  en versiones anteriores a `Android M` uso

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress()
```

En `Android M` obtengo el valor `02:00:00:00:00:00`

En la documentación oficial detallan los Cambios en [Android 6](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

> Para acceder a los identificadores de hardware de dispositivos
>   externos cercanos por medio de escaneos de Bluetooth y Wi-Fi, ahora tu
>   app debe tener los permisos ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION o
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:

He añadido al `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Y aceptado con la petición de permisos en tiempo de ejecutación.

¿Hay alguna otra manera para obtener las direcciones MAC del Bluetooth y del WIFFI?

Answer (score 1):

Este es mi método anterior:

```
   public static String getMacAddress(Context ctx) {
        String mac = (ctx != null) ? ((WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress() : null;
        return mac == null ? "" : mac;
    }
```

pero hay algo importante que comentar para OS 6.0+

[Acceso al identificador de hardware Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

> **Para brindar una mejor protección de datos a los usuarios**, a partir de
>   esta versión, en Android se quita el acceso por programación al
>   identificador de hardware local del dispositivo para apps que usen las
>   Wi-Fi y Bluetooth API. Los métodos WifiInfo.getMacAddress() y
>   BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() **ahora muestran un valor constante de
>   02:00:00:00:00:00.**

Siempre he usado el método que comentas pero el problema es que ahora por seguridad, envía el valor constante `02:00:00:00:00:00`, por lo tanto hay que evitar usar este valor ya que no esta expuesto por seguridad.

Pero siempre hay otra forma hehe,

```
  public static String getMacAddress() {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

                byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                if (macBytes == null) {
                    return "";
                }

                StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : macBytes) {
                    res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                }

                if (res1.length() > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                }
                return res1.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Interesante y el MAC del Bluetooth del dispositivo como se obtendría?

Comment: ups tu pregunta es  bluetooth, usa BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress()

Comment: Modifico la pregunta que sea valido para Wifi y Bluetooth que son los afectados con el cambio de Android M

Answer (score 1):

Cree esta versión del código en kotlin por si alguien lo necesitara ya que hay un cambio en la conversion de bytes. Este seria un método público para una clase en kotlin

```kotlin
object MacAdmin {
val macAddress: String?
    get() {
        try {
            val all: List<NetworkInterface> =
                Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
            for (nif in all) {
                if (!nif.name.equals("wlan0", ignoreCase = true)) continue
                val macBytes = nif.hardwareAddress ?: return ""
                val res1 = StringBuilder()
                for (b in macBytes) {
                    res1.append(String.format("%02x", b) + ":")
                }
                if (res1.length > 0) {
                    res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length - 1)
                }
                return res1.toString()
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            return ex.message
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Me ha gustado la idea de pasar una cadena de bytes a mac byte : byte :